# C++ Qt base class virtual destructor

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, destructor

Do we need a virtual destructor for a classes which are gonna be used in Qt-way: set `QObject`-parent which will call in QObject's destructor `deleteLater()` or something like that for any object for which it was set as parent?

For example:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
public:
    MyWidget() {
        w = new QWidget(this);
        // "w" will be deleted automatically by parent MyWidget::QWidget::QObject's destructor afaik
    }
private:
    QWidget *w;
}
```

Do we need a virtual destructor for `MyWidget` class if it is gonna be inherited? I see no reason for this because it does not delete anything and each property of the class which is derived from `QObject` will be deleted from **MyWidget::QWidget::QObject**'s destructor.

Comment: I don't understand the question: anything that derives from `QObject` already has a virtual destructor already. You can add a class-specific one, but that's only an addition. There's no reason to add empty destructors, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly write an (empty) `virtual` destructor because `QWidget` already marks its distructor as `virtual`, so automatically all destructors of the class hierarchy are `virtual`.

But in general, if you write a class that is going to be inherited (and doesn't already have a base class with a `virtual` destructor), always specify a `virtual` destructor, otherwise things will blow up badly if anyone tries to destroy an object of your class hierarchy through a pointer of the base class type.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter if you add it or not as `QObject` inherited by `QWidget` has a virtual destructor, and this is propagated through the whole hierarchy.